# Web Application with Redux, how to deal with logic only needs to execute once

Tags: javascript, mvvm, frontend, redux

Says we are using an mvvm framework with redux, everytime store dispatch an action, I'd update my component as

```
Store.subscribe(() => {
  var { Order, Payment } = Store.getState():

  this.order = Order;
  this.payment = Payment;

  this.setCountDown(Order.leftTime);
  this.checkIsPaymentValid(Payment);
});
```

here, `setCountDown` & `checkIsPaymentValid` only need to execute once and will never been called sincethen. As a result, I'm currently adding status to component and it becomes like old jquery way which turns something similar to below:

```
switch(Order.status) {
  case ORDER_STATUS_NORMAL:
    break;
  case ORDER_HAS_SET_COUNTDOWN:
    break;
}
```

any suggestions on dealing with such conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to execute some logic **based on the action rather than on the current state**, it is usually a sign that it should happen as part of dispatching the action. In other words, perform these side effects before or after `dispatch()` rather than in the change handler.

If this logic spans across multiple components, you might want to consider using something like [Redux Saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga) that lets you define long-running “sagas” that can “take” actions and execute some side effects or dispatch more actions to the store.

Comment: I agree. It has been days & currently I'm designing my data flow as two parts: 1. you care about the result 2. you care about the state. Every time you call an action it would return a promise & dispatch(or not) state. Anyone who use it can choose there own way

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to unscribribe in the end of your handler. From [redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe):

> To unsubscribe the change listener, invoke the function returned by subscribe.

So, you can split handler and always change `this.order` and `this.payment`, but call `setCountDown` and `checkIsPaymentValid` only once:

```
Store.subscribe(() => {
  var { Order, Payment } = Store.getState():

  this.order = Order;
  this.payment = Payment;   
});


const unsubscribe = Store.subscribe(() => {
  var { Order, Payment } = Store.getState():

  this.setCountDown(Order.leftTime);
  this.checkIsPaymentValid(Payment);
  unsubscribe();
});
```

Comment: That's a gr8 point !
anyway in my current situation, my main focus is data binding, one-time logic is just part of it, I won't give up data binding because of this single part :)